# Find vector overlap from the start

Tags: r

I am looking for an efficient way to get the first `k` elements that are the same between two vectors in `R`.

For example:

```
orderedIntersect(c(1,2,3,4), c(1,2,5,4))
# [1] 1 2
orderedIntersect(c(1,2,3), c(1,2,3,4))
# [1] 1 2 3
```

This is the same as the `intersect` behavior, but any values after the first mismatch should be dropped.

I also want this to work for strings.

So far, the solution that I have is this:

```
orderedIntersect <- function(a,b) {
  a <- as.vector(a)
  NAs <- is.na(match(a, as.vector(b)))
  last <- ifelse(any(NAs), min(which(NAs)) - 1, length(a))
  a[1:last]
}
```

I am troubled by the fact that I have to iterate over `n` input elements `6` times: `match`, `is.na`, `any`, `which`, `min`, and the subset `[]`.

Clearly, it would be faster to write an external `C` function (with a `for` loop and a `break`), but I am wondering if there is any clever `R` trick I can use here.

Comment: Are you testing for consecutive intersection or equality? E.g. should `orderedIntersect(c(1, 2, 3, 4, 6), c(3, 1, 2, 5, 6))` return `c(1, 2, 3)` or `numeric(0)`? Also, should `orderedIntersect(c(6, 1, 3, 4), c(5, 1, 3, 2))` return `c(1, 3)`?

Comment: @alexis_laz Equality (or consecutive intersection starting at element 1). Both of your examples should return `numeric(0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work:

```
#test data
a <- c(1,2,3,4)
b <- c(1,2,5,4)
c <- c(1,2,8,9,9,9,9,3)
d <- c(9,0,0,8)
empty <- c()
string1 <- c("abc", "def", "ad","k")
string2 <- c("abc", "def", "c", "lds")

#function
orderedIntersect <- function(a, b) {
  l <- min(length(a), length(b))
  if (l == 0) return(numeric(0))
  a1 <- a[1:l]
  comp <- a1 != b[1:l]
  if (all(!comp)) return(a1)
  a1[ 0:(min(which(comp)) - 1) ]
}

#testing
orderedIntersect(a,b)
# [1] 1 2
orderedIntersect(a,c)
# [1] 1 2
orderedIntersect(a,d)
# numeric(0)
orderedIntersect(a, empty)
# numeric(0)
orderedIntersect(string1,string2)
# [1] "abc" "def"
```

Comment: I like this solution - [edited in some edge cases (including equal vectors :) ]. This gets to the core of the solution, which is the same as @CathG's.
Thanks!

Comment: @Manbroski thanks for edit, couldn't think deep enough for edge cases.

Answer (score 2):

You can compare the values of your vectors and drop elements when the first `FALSE` is reached:

```
orderedIntersect <- function(a,b) {
     # check the lengths are equal and if not, "cut" the vectors so they are (to avoid warnings)
     l_a <- length(a) ; l_b <- length(b) 
     if(l_a != l_b) {m_l <- min(l_a, l_b) ; a <- a[1:m_l] ; b <- b[1:m_l]}
     # compare the elements : they are equal if both are not NA and have the same value or if both are NA
     comp <- (!is.na(a) & !is.na(b) & a==b) | (is.na(a) & is.na(b))
     # return the right vector : nothing if the first elements do not match, everything if all elements match or just the part that match
     if(!comp[1]) return(c()) else if (all(comp)) return(a) else return(a[1:(which(!comp)[1]-1)])
}

orderedIntersect(c(1,2,3,4), c(1,2,5,4))
#[1] 1 2
orderedIntersect(c(1,2,3), c(1,2,3,4))
#[1] 1 2 3
orderedIntersect(c(1,2,3), c(2,3,4))
#NULL
```

Comment: While this a little cryptic, I like the approach. Thanks~

Comment: @Manbroski, thanks, sorry for the cryptic part, I've added some explanations to clarify :-)

Answer (score 2):

The simple C solution (for integers) isn't really any longer than the R version, but it would be a little more work to extend to all the other classes.

```
library(inline)
orderedIntersect <- cfunction(
    signature(x='integer', y='integer'),
    body='  
  int i, l = length(x) > length(y) ? length(y) : length(x),
    *xx = INTEGER(x), *yy = INTEGER(y);
  SEXP res;
  for (i = 0; i < l; i++) if (xx[i] != yy[i]) break;
  PROTECT(res = allocVector(INTSXP, i));
  for (l = 0; l < i; l++) INTEGER(res)[l] = xx[l];
  UNPROTECT(1);
  return res;'
)

## Tests
a <- c(1L,2L,3L,4L)
b <- c(1L,2L,5L,4L)
c <- c(1L,2L,8L,9L,9L,9L,9L,3L)
d <- c(9L,0L,0L,8L)

orderedIntersect(a,b)
# [1] 1 2
orderedIntersect(a,c)
# [1] 1 2
orderedIntersect(a,d)
# integer(0)
orderedIntersect(a, integer())
# integer(0)
```

Comment: Thanks for an `inline` example. This will certainly come handy down the line for me.